# How to interpret $x^{\alpha}$, for $\alpha \in (0, \infty)\diagdown \mathbb N$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0, \infty)\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)= x^{n}, \ (x\in \mathbb R , n\in \mathbb N$).(here we interpret $x^{n}$ as product of $x$ with itself $n$ times, that is, $x^{n}= x\cdot \cdot \cdot x$) Clearly, $f$ is differentiable and its derivative is given by,  $f'(x)= nx^{n-1}.$

> **My Questions**: (I) Let $x\in (0, \infty)$. How to interpret $x^{\alpha}$, for $\alpha \in (0, \infty)\diagdown \mathbb N$ ? (II) Let $g:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(x)= x^{\alpha}, \ (\alpha \in (0, \infty)\diagdown \mathbb N).$ Can we expect $g$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, and its derivative is given by $g'(x)= \alpha x^{\alpha -1}$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: for a rational number p/q in R, define x^p/q as the qth root of x^p. For an irrational number y in R, y is the limit of a sequence of rationals and x^y is defined as the limit of x^ri where limit ri = y. (The interesting part of the definition is to prove that x^y has the same well defined value for any sequence which converges to y). The derivative is defined by the same route.

Answer (score 3):

The typical way is to **define**
$$ x^a = \exp(a \cdot \log{x}) $$

Since $\exp$ can be defined for very general spaces, and $\log$ as its inverse, this approach is very general (if perhaps unsatisfying).

To fully answer your question, you can use chain rule to recover your expected derivatives.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that another way to interpret these is to first extend the "intuitive" notion of exponents to rational numbers. This is quite straight-forward. First, we all agree that $(x^n)^m$ should be $x^{nm}$. Second, since that is true, we can make sense of raising things to $1/n$ as an inverse of exponentiating to the $n$. (Indeed, by our above, agreed upon understanding, $(x^{1/n})^n=x$.)

Thus, we can now consider $x^{n/m}$. Finally, we apply real analysis magic and consider sequences of rational numbers which converge to our desired irrational power.